# How do I multiply and add columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I basically want to do this function as a new column.

```
New Column = a1*a2 + b1*b2 + c1*c2
```

where a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2 are all existing columns with numerical values in each cell. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you just want to do this as part of a SELECT or do you want to permanently create a new column that is changed each time you update one of the others?

Comment: As part of a select, when I use * it responds with ERROR:  operator does not exist: text * character varying

Comment: Well, then obviously those columns are not "numerical" values - at least one of them is defined as `text` and at least one other is defined as `varchar` . If they really are "numbers" they should be defined as `numeric` or `integer`

Comment: Yes just checked, they are text and varchar, how do I change them to numeric or integer as the cells are all numbers

Comment: `alter table ... alter column ... type ...` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check columns a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2 has "type" is bigint;

And use QSL:

ALTER TABLE demo.abc ADD COLUMN d bigint;

Update demo.abc set d = abc.a1 * abc.a2 + abc.b1 * abc.b2 + abc.b1*abc.c2;